# Cpp multi line macro containing preprocessor commands

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to replace the 3 sames lines of code by a single one in order to make my code more compact and readable.

Using a multi line macro was my first approach that I tried to do this.

So, I want to replace :

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_IN_BINARY
    *fileOutputStream << endl;
#endif
```

By a single macro call.

So I added

```
#define WRITE_ENDLINE   \
#ifndef OUTPUT_IN_BINARY   \
    *fileOutputStream << endl; \
#endif
```

earlier in my code, and I replaced my lines with :

```
 WRITE_ENDLINE
```

But I ran into a set of errors :

```
>  error C2121: '#': invalid character: possibly the result of a macro expansion
>  error C2065: 'ifndef': undeclared identifier
>  error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
>  error C2297: '*': illegal, right operand has type 'QDataStream *'
>  error C2065: 'endif': undeclared identifier
```

I studied some other questions here and various docs, but I didn't get what's wrong here ? Maybe a syntax error because I'm mixing other macros commands ?

I know that there may be other solutions to achieve my goal, but I wanted to try the macro solution...

thanks !

Comment: This is a [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I'm pretty sure that macros are not proper tool for jobs which is actually a problem. Please answer why you think you need macros!

Comment: Well because multi-line macro seems to be a possible solution to my problem ?
https://www.scaler.com/topics/cpp-macro/
But it seems that i can't contains other macros ?

Comment: Please read description of xy problem in link I've provided and reconsider your comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it... I'm learning cpp and for my problem, with my actual knowledge, it seems for me that it could be possible to solve it with macros. I may be completely wrong of course. But I didn't want to ask my question without showing that I tried something ?

Should I rephrase my initial question ?

Comment: Please note that macros are evil. If you are learning C++ do not focus your effort on them. There are lots of other more important topics/features of C++. Macros are C-feature which should be avoided as much as possible. For now you need to use only header guards.

Comment: The point about an XY problem is that you ask us about your solution to an (for us) unknown problem. Often, knowing the actual and underlying problem that you need to solve can help us come up with better solutions. Always ask about the underlying and actual problem directly, and tell (and show) us the solutions you have tried and give us details how they don't work.

Comment: Regarding the macro, the backslash at the end is a line-continuation character, the compiler will treat the macro as a single line. So your macro is really `#define WRITE_ENDLINE #ifndef OUTPUT_IN_BINARY *fileOutputStream << endl; #endif` as **a single line**. Which will of course not work. Macros are not the right solution here. But since you don't tell us the actual problem you need to solve, we can't help you find the correct (or at least a working) solution.

Comment: I updated the question, I hope that's is clearer. Thanks guys !

Comment: @yoruk a better solution in c++ would be to write your own i/o stream manipulator class, instead of a macro.

Comment: When I see more details I'm even more sure macros are wrong tool for this task. Still there is not enough details to address issue properly. Last sentence can be translated to: "when you holding a hammer everything looks like a nail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your definition attempt

```
#define WRITE_ENDLINE   \
#ifndef OUTPUT_IN_BINARY   \
    *fileOutputStream << endl; \
#endif
```

I guess that what you want is the following:
If I use `WRITE_ENDLINE`, then in case that `WRITE_ENDLINE` is not defined, I want it expanded to `*fileOutputStream << endl;`.
You do not specify what you want otherwise, what you want expanded in case that  `WRITE_ENDLINE` is defined.
Let's assume that you are fine with an empty line; a reasonable assumption I believe, because you do not mention any alternative code.
So for that goal please use this definition:

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_IN_BINARY
#define WRITE_ENDLINE  *fileOutputStream << endl;
#else
#define WRITE_ENDLINE 
#endif
```

That way you get the wanted code in the case you are thinking of, but still a valid, though empty, definition in the other case. That in turn allows you to use the macro whether or not the `OUTPUT_IN_BINARY` is defined.

Comment: this is the thing OP ask for, but not thing he actually needs.

Comment: They ask for some magic to make a multiline macro inside a single macro definition, which is impossible. This is neither impossible nor a single-definition-multiline-preprocessor-construct. I also think that what they need is this. Please elaborate why you think differently. @MarekR

Comment: Because OP should not be using macros in the first place, given that the macros are being used as replacements for if statements.

Comment: Using macros is dangerous and of questionable use, I agree. But the goal is to replace three lines (let's allow that to also apply to something that can be squeezed into one line) by one and they decided to do that by macro. The benefit is perceived readability, at leat for OP. I am not even contradicting the XY impression here, but both the X and the Y are recognisable here (the problem of most XY questions is that one is not visible and focus is too much on the other). A solution can be given. I think that helping to understand macros is a possible answer here. Even if using them is doubted.

Comment: Well again sorry for being unclear at first but yes my goal was, with replacing my 3 lines,  to make a condition regarding the state of OUTPUT_IN_BINARY. I understand now why it's impossible to do it the multi-line macro way, and the solution here works for me.

Comment: The understanding was my goal. Using the solution is your decision. Maybe a kind C++ expert provides an elegant way to do this in C++; because I consider my answer a c-preprocessor answer for a c-preprocessor question. There is a tag for that, you might want to change the C++ tag you used for that pre-processor tag.